# Add dependsOn annotation on bean from external library

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I want my bean to be constructed after a bean from an external library, but when I use the name of the bean it doesn't seem to get picked up by Spring.

`@depensOn("externalbean")` doesn't work.

What do I need more to allow this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a ComponentScan annotation of the package in which the required bean is found.
Something like

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.external.bean.package")
public class MyConfiguration{

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("externalBeanName")
    public MyDependency mydependency() {
         ....
    }
}
```